# Creating constant from sort in Z3 Python API

Tags: python, z3, z3py

Given a Z3 Sort and a string `s` I am trying to create a Z3 constant of that sort named `s`.

For instance, given `IntSort()` and the name `"x"` I'd like to get an integer constant named `"x"`.

I know I can get it calling `Int('x')` but since I am creating this variables dynamically I cannot predict what sort a given variable will have. What I have to do is to create a variable of the same sort of the one provided by the system but with a new name (which I have to be able to specify at runtime).

To be more specific,

```
1. I get a model for a user defined formula calling the Z3 Solver on it, 
2. I save it in a database (recording for each assignment in such a model the variable name, the value to be assigned to it and the sort of that variable)
3. I retrieve that assignment after a while from the database and I try it o a new formula having the same variables of the original one.
```

In order to do so I turn each assignment into a clause of the form `var == value`, I add them to the solver together with the target formula and I check for satisfiability.

Up to now I only worked with the integer sort so I hardcoded the transformation of string to constants using the `Int` function. Now I am trying to generalize the approach to different logics and different datatypes so I need something to create the right constant out of what I saved in my database.

Is this approach reasonable in your opinion? Do you think there any trick to do it better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use the 'Const' function.
For example:

```
A = DeclareSort('A')
a = Const('a', A)
```